# Destroy record instead of update in form nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I have a model `opening_times` that records opening times of shops.

```
create_table "opening_times", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "day"
    t.time "morning"
    t.time "evening"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "shop_id"
    t.index ["shop_id"]
  end
```

This model is updated only through a nested form in the `edit` action of `shops` controller. I have no `opening_times` controller.

Then basically what I can do is pretty much limited: the `update` action.

Though I have a problem: when there used to be opening times for a specific day, let's say tuesday, and the user want to make that day not worked, the user makes both fields `morning` and `evening` blanks.

I could save empty values in the database but it would be better to actually delete the record for tuesday.

then in the model file I have set this :

```
before_save :delete_records_with_missing_hours

private 

def delete_records_with_missing_hours
    if self.morning.blank? or self.evening.blank?
        self.destroy
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there a way to delete a record that was intended to be updated at the model level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Rails Way to handle this. It can be done very easily, but you need to do it from your Shop model. In that model insert this:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :opening_times, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :reject_opening_time?

  def reject_opening_time?(attributes)
    persisted = attributes[:id].present?
    time_values = attributes.slice(:morning, :evening).values
    without_time = time_values.any?(&:blank?)
    attributes.merge!(_destroy: true) if persisted and without_time
    without_time && !persisted # Return false so as to reject new opening_time if any time attributes are empty
  end
end
```

Now for each `opening_time` nested record, Rails will evaluate the time attributes. If any time value is blank, it will treat the record appropriately. If the record is persisted, it will add a `_destroy` attribute, which will destroy the nested record when you save the parent. If the record is not persisted, it will be rejected (ignored) when you save the parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed. I don't understand the fourth line with the merge though as it is quite elaborate syntax for me .. but I will dig a bit.

Comment: Is this really the rails way? I don't think reject_if should be used to manipulate record attributes. Besides, if you would add multiple models to the accepts_nested_attributes_for method, it will fail. It should be agnostic of the model. Also, I feel that this isn't a task for the Shop model, as it concerns a different model. Probably this should already be fixed in the View, by setting `_destroy:true` on the record that got the opening times removed.

Comment: @bo-oz This method works, it uses included Rails tools, and it doesn't require a cron job. Setting `_destroy: true` in a view seems counterproductive as the logic would need to be duplicated by any client that submits nested attributes. Adding another nested model could (and should) be done with a separate `accepts_nested_attributes_for` line. I'm open to setting `_destroy: true` in a callback either on the parent or the child model, but haven't tested to see what would work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better of creating some kind of maintenance script for this action. Like a rake task or something. So periodically you run a simple find and destroy:

```
OpeningTime.where(morning:nil, evening:nil).destroy_all
```

Just run this on a daily or weekly basis to clean up your database and don't bother with the records at the moment of saving.

I think the problem with your current code is that you are deleting the record in the before_save, so this creates two problems:

1/ What should rails do if this is not a persisted record, but a new one? Destroy would fail and with it the entire transaction will rollback (take a look at your console)

2/ Even if the record was persisted, deleting it would then work, but the save action that will be performed next would fail, also resulting in a rollback.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation on why this is failling, it actually rolls back everytime. My solution was to go through the (up to) 7 children of the shop models and check for records with empty `morning` or `evening` fields and kill it from the controller. But this seem very redundant and ugly. @moveson has actually given me the solution in the other answer (need to do all this in the parent)

Answer (score 0):

If you rather not have fields with empty values for `morning` and `evening`, why not just validate the existence of those fields? It would be much more cleaner then using external methods to validate that situation.

Firstly, you should put this in the `Shop` model:

```rb
validates_associated :opening_times
```

This code will make sure that your association is validated before being inserted/updated

Now you can put a validation in the `OpeningTime` model, like this:

```
validates :morning, :evening, presence: true
```

And if you just wanna do that in the update action, you can even do:

```
validates :morning, :evening, presence: true, on: :update
```

And if you wanted at least one of the values to be present, you can also use:

```
validate :morning_and_evening_validation

def morning_and_evening_validation
  morning.present? || evening.present?
end
```

I think mostly it's much more cleaner and readable.